# Android: How to make a gridview of equal proportions within the Java code

Tags: android, gridview, grid, imageview, baseadapter

I am working on an application which has a main screen with a gridview layout. 
As it stands currently, I am hardcoding in DP numbers for the height and width of the boxes, which I obviously do not want to do. How to I create code that will determine the users' screen size and match the boxes accordingly so that someone with a large phone like a note will view the same thing as someone on a droid mini? IE, when hardcoding to 500dp on each side, it looks like this:
[image]

But my goal is to make it look like this on every screen size:
[image]

Currently, this is the Java code I have:

public class ActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
//Array of Icons that will be used as menu choices
public static int[] imageOptions = {
        R.drawable.vacation_quota, //Position 0
        R.drawable.revenue_deficit, //Position 1
            //+ many more options...
    };

private Context context;

//Constructor to pass context back to Main class
public ActivityAdapter(Context applicationContext) {

    context = applicationContext;
}

//Number of elements to be displayed on the grid
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return imageOptions.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv;
    if(convertView != null){
        iv = (ImageView) convertView;
    } else {
        iv = new ImageView(context);

                    //Here I have it hard coded to match a 480px width. Here is where I need to change it, just not sure how
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));

        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); //Center the cropping

    }

    //Sets the image to correspond to its position within the array.
    iv.setImageResource(imageOptions[position]);
    return iv;
}
```

Any ideas? I think logically I want to figure out the screen dimensions and use them to make the image dimensions match, just not sure how. Research from other threads has not helped a great deal so hoping I can get a simpler answer here with code posting.

Comment: Only kind of... The code here would not work sadly as I am not able to make this work outside of an activity class, and I am trying to avoid changing the fundamental structure of the app. I ended up just going with a simple recommendation which was:
   iv = new ImageView(context);
   
   WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
   Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
   
   float width2 = display.getWidth();
   
   int length = (int) (width2/2);
   
   iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(length, length));

Answer (score 0):

You should get the screen width and height. Then use these values to dynamically set height and width for each cell

Comment: I agree gand, that is actually what I am asking how to do in this question.

Comment: Use ` getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` then get width and height

Comment: When I use 'getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();' it comes up with "undefined as type main". How exactly do I use this? Is it set equal to a variable? Do I need to create an object to use it?

Comment: Yes; assign it to an object of DisplayMetrics and use widthPixels and heigthPixels to get dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        setContentView(new ViewGroup(this) {
            private RelativeLayout[] items = new RelativeLayout[9];
            private int width, height, itemWidth, itemHeight;
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    items[i] = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
                    float[] hsv = new float[] {360 * r.nextFloat(), .50f, .75f};
                    items[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
                    addView(items[i]);

                    // UPDATE ////////////////////////////////////
                    ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());
                    switch (i) {
                    case 0: // top left
                    case 1: // top center
                    case 2: // top right
                    case 3: // center left
                    case 4: // center center
                    case 5: // center right
                    case 6: // bottom left
                    case 7: // bottom center
                    case 8: // bottom right
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        break;
                    }
                    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    ));
                    items[i].addView(image);
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onMeasure(int wMS, int hMS) {
                width = MeasureSpec.getSize(wMS);
                height = MeasureSpec.getSize(hMS);
                itemWidth = width / 3;
                itemHeight = height / 3;
                wMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(itemWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                hMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(itemHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                measureChildren(wMS, hMS);
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    l = itemWidth * (i % 3);
                    t = itemHeight * (i / 3);
                    r = l + itemWidth;
                    b = t + itemHeight;
                    items[i].layout(l, t, r, b);
                }
            }
        });
        super.onCreate(state);
    }

}
```

Output-

[image]

Edit-

For creating scrollable grid view see this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Just copy and paste and check output. Then modify code according to your requirement.

Comment: Kanwaljit, Thank you for such a thorough response! I am having a little trouble trying to make the code work for me though. First off, I will have more than 9 items, so I am trying to figure out how to make this a scroll view that allows the user to scroll down and see more options below.
Second, to make these pictures clickable to where they open an activity, whereabouts would I put that code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not able to use some of the recommendations here and had to use a deprecated method to retain my app structure. The code specifically that was added to mine was:

```
        iv = new ImageView(context);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        float width2 = display.getWidth();

        int length = (int) (width2/2);

        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(length, length));
```

With this, the height and width would crop to the right size depending on the size of the screen.